# C# XmlSerializer ignores xs:attribute with types other than xs:string

Tags: c#, attributes, xmlserializer

my problem seems very odd and I did not find any other with that problem, so I guess it is a very simple and stupid mistake, which I can't seem to find out.

I have an XSD, from which I generate a class structure using xsd.exe. I "fill" my object with values, but when serializing it to XML it ignores all class-properties which are not of type `string`.

```
var myGraph = new graph();
myGraph.myString = "hallo";
myGraph.myInt = 80;

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(graph));
TextWriter writeFileStream = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(outFolder, outFile));
serializer.Serialize(writeFileStream, myGraph);
writeFileStream.Close();
```

I expected:

```
<graph xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
    myString="hallo" 
    myInt="80"
/>
```

The actual output is:

```
<graph xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    myString="hallo" 
/>
```

The attribute `myInt` has been ignored. If I define it as a string, it will also appear, but as any other type it will not show up. If I declare it `required` and leave it `null`, it will be serialized as `myInt="0"`.

What am I missing?

Some details:

XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="graph">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="myString" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:attribute name="myInt" type="xs:int" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

generated class:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=false)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class graph {
    private string myStringField;
    private int myIntField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string myString {
        get { return this.myStringField; }
        set { this.myStringField = value; }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public int myInt {
        get { return this.myIntField; }
        set { this.myIntField = value; }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool myIntSpecified {
        get { return this.myIntFieldSpecified; }
        set { this.myIntFieldSpecified = value; }
    }
```

Comment: In the generated class you posted, the myIntSpecified function references the myIntFieldSpecified variable, but I don't see this variable defined anywhere in the class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XSD will add an additional "specified" field for all properties that are value types. When using .NET serialization with value types, you will always need to specify the field's value and set the matching "specified" property to true.

Change you code to this and it will work as expected:

```
var myGraph = new graph();
myGraph.myString = "hallo";
myGraph.myInt = 80;
myGraph.myIntSpecified = true;
```

Comment: Hmm, I noticed that field of course and I saw it many times when working with xsd.exe. I just did not imagine, it has to be set to `true` "manually".

Comment: Many thanks for this hint, I was going crazy about this bug. My boss would say "this is chapter one - you should know that". Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but remember something similar.
See the generated 'myIntSpecified' field? You should set this to true.

xsd.exe has some big limitations, you could google for alternatives, or simply remember setting it to true every time. :)

Comment: Well, I used to use `svcutil.exe` instead of `xsd.exe`, but I had a lot of trouble using `xs:attributes` and it showed, that `xsd.exe` was a lot easier to use in that case. In other cases I still stick to `svcutil.exe`. Thanks for your reply, I'd vote you up, if I had more reputation points.

Comment: @Nylle: No problem, @pmartin's explanation is nice. One more tip, you can also use the [CodeDomProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.aspx), and a XmlSchemaImporter and a XmlCodeExporter to generate code for CodeDOM. Afterwards you can adjust the generated code through CodeDOM. This can give you extra control over the generated code when desired.

Answer (score 0):

There something else going on your side my friend. I did compile the code and it worked perfectly:

class:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = false)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class graph
{
    private string myStringField;
    private int myIntField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string myString
    {
        get { return this.myStringField; }
        set { this.myStringField = value; }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public int myInt
    {
        get { return this.myIntField; }
        set { this.myIntField = value; }
    }


}
```

Code:

```
    graph g = new graph() {myInt = 80, myString = "ali"};
    XmlSerializer xss = new XmlSerializer(typeof (graph));
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    xss.Serialize(ms, g);
    StreamReader sb = new StreamReader(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ReadToEnd());
```

Output:

```
<graph xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org
/2001/XMLSchema-instance" myString="ali" myInt="80" />
```

Comment: I did not generate. I copied the class from his and just wrote a simple test harness.

Comment: @Aliostad - Your class (at least what you posted above) is different than the generated class from the original post. You are missing the myIntSpecified field in the class you posted.

Comment: Yes, but what is that?? `myIntFieldSpecified` has not been specified and is missing from your class.

Comment: @Aliostad - I should have said that you're missing the myIntSpecified function,not the field. I agree, the field is missing from the original generated class and I'm not sure why.